# Right-Click Menu Support on Excel for Mac UserForm

Tags: excel, vba, macos, userform

I have an Excel workbook that has a UserForm which allows users to display information from an excel table on a worksheet through dropdown lists (ComboBoxes) or TextBoxes. I found out that UserForms don't seem to have a native right click function for the components inside them, so I set out to implement it as not every user knows about Ctrl + C, V, or X. I found an implementation of a right click menu from [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/07/using-copypaste-in-userforms/), added a cut function and enabled it for use on ComboBoxes.

I test any VBA code changes on my Windows computer in which it works wonderfully; however, there are a couple of Excel for Mac users who receive an [error 430 run-time message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/class-does-not-support-automation-or-does-not-support-expected-interface) when launching the UserForm from the command button on the excel sheet. Everyone that uses this workbook is running the latest version of Office 365 (for Mac/Windows).

Implementing the class module is simple enough:

```
Option Explicit

Dim cBar As clsBar

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'Copy/Cut/Paste Support from Class Module clsBar
    Set cBar = New clsBar
    cBar.Initialize Me

End Sub
```

And here is the class module code for the right-click menu:

```
Option Explicit

'Popup objects
Private cmdBar As CommandBar
Private WithEvents cmdCutButton As CommandBarButton
Private WithEvents cmdCopyButton As CommandBarButton
Private WithEvents cmdPasteButton As CommandBarButton

'UserForm to use
Private fmUserform As Object

'Control array of textbox
Private colControls As Collection

'Textbox and ComboBox Control
Private WithEvents tbTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
Private WithEvents tbComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox

'Adds all the textbox in the userform to use the popup bar
Sub Initialize(ByVal UF As Object)
    Dim Ctl As MSForms.Control
    Dim cBar As clsBar

    For Each Ctl In UF.Controls

        'This does not check for textboxes or comboboxes inside frames or other objects, not necessary for this implementation

        If TypeName(Ctl) = "TextBox" Then

            'Check if we have initialized the control array
            If colControls Is Nothing Then
               Set colControls = New Collection
               Set fmUserform = UF
               'Create the popup
              CreateBar
            End If

            'Create a new instance of this class for each textbox
            Set cBar = New clsBar
            cBar.AssignTextBox Ctl, cmdBar

            'Add it to the control array
            colControls.Add cBar
        End If

        If TypeName(Ctl) = "ComboBox" Then

            'Check if we have initialized the control array
            If colControls Is Nothing Then
               Set colControls = New Collection
               Set fmUserform = UF
               'Create the popup
              CreateBar
            End If


            'Create a new instance of this class for each combobox
            Set cBar = New clsBar
            cBar.AssignComboBox Ctl, cmdBar

            'Add it to the control array
            colControls.Add cBar 
        End If
   Next Ctl
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()

    'Delete the commandbar when the class is destroyed
    On Error Resume Next
    cmdBar.Delete
End Sub

'Click event of the cut button
Private Sub cmdCutButton_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)

    fmUserform.ActiveControl.Cut
    CancelDefault = True
End Sub

'Click event of the copy button
Private Sub cmdCopyButton_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)

    fmUserform.ActiveControl.Copy
    CancelDefault = True
End Sub

'Click event of the paste button
Private Sub cmdPasteButton_Click(ByVal Ctrl As Office.CommandBarButton, CancelDefault As Boolean)

    fmUserform.ActiveControl.Paste
    CancelDefault = True
End Sub


'Right click event of each textbox
Private Sub tbTextBox_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
      ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    If Button = 2 And Shift = 0 Then
      'Display the popup
        cmdBar.ShowPopup
    End If
End Sub

'Right click event of each combobox
Private Sub tbComboBox_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
      ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    If Button = 2 And Shift = 0 Then
        'Display the popup
        cmdBar.ShowPopup
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CreateBar()
    Set cmdBar = Application.CommandBars.Add(, msoBarPopup, False, True)

    'We’ll use the builtin Copy and Paste controls
    Set cmdCutButton = cmdBar.Controls.Add(ID:=21)
    Set cmdCopyButton = cmdBar.Controls.Add(ID:=19)
    Set cmdPasteButton = cmdBar.Controls.Add(ID:=22)
End Sub

'Assigns the Textbox and the CommandBar to this instance of the class
Sub AssignTextBox(TT As MSForms.TextBox, Bar As CommandBar)

    Set tbTextBox = TT
    Set cmdBar = Bar
End Sub

Sub AssignComboBox(TC As MSForms.ComboBox, Bar As CommandBar)

    Set tbComboBox = TC
    Set cmdBar = Bar
End Sub
```

I'm certain this code is causing the error because using a copy of my workbook that does **not** have this code implemented in it works fine for both platforms. I will admit that I'm not experienced with VBA, especially so with Excel for Mac, so I'm unsure what exactly would be causing the error other than MSForms or Controls not existing in Excel for Mac. Microsoft's website says that [commandbar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbar) has been superseded by a ['Fluent Ribbon' user interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/overview-of-the-office-fluent-ribbon), however, from briefly reading the documentation and watching a video or two, nothing suggests to me that it could be used in the same way as a commandbar for a VBA UserForm.

Ideally, I would like to keep this level of functionality within my UserForm for both Windows and Mac users. I'm not too fussed about removing the code all together, but if someone is able to point me in the right direction for what I should be using/doing instead of the above implementation I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The error is caused because of the line `Set cmdCutButton = cmdBar.Controls.Add(ID:=21)` If I am not wrong (And I could be wrong), you cannot add buttons to the right click menu in Mac because it is not supported.

Comment: I am afraid I may be right... https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win014.htm

Comment: @user10186832. Seems like Ron has removed all his content but you can get the data for this link using the time machine. Here is the link https://web.archive.org/web/20180421201509/https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win014.htm